# Configuration values for event system

Tags: web8.5, event-system

I am working on event system code (sdl web 8.5) and need to place a config component path in configuration file(similar to app.config).

I followed the post https://www.curlette.com/?p=1403 but still the value isn't picked from the config file even though its name is same as that of dll with just .config added at the end. Any other suggestions to achieve this other than adding the config key in tcmservicehost.config file.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information so that we can help. Include the config file and show full path filenames for the dll and config. Check that your config file is valid xml.

Answer (score 2):

Like Chris mentioned in the comments, please provide more information so people would be able to help you. But, here are some pointers that may help you identify and solve the problem:

- Are you using Curlette's `ConfigurationManagerEventSystem` class in your custom event handler to open the configuration XML and return the Configuration object instance? Your solution tree and the app settings value you are trying to get from the config in your event handler should look similar to the one in the screenshot below.

[image]

- The config and the event handler DLL should be in the same location and the full path with the name of the DLL should be included in the `<extensions>` element in the `Tridion.ContentManager.config`.

[image]

- The SDL Web Content Manager Service Host service and IIS should be restarted.

If you have done the above steps, you should be able to read the values from the config. Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding onto Sabarish' answer, I've leveraged Roberts code in an open-source event handler extension on my GitHub. Feel free to reference the code there if it's helpful: https://github.com/joshhebb/tridion-publish-mirror/tree/master/Publish.Mirror